# readLine of BufferedReader does not change file pointer

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, randomaccessfile

My app reads text file line by line and record offset of each line until the end of file. offset returns changed value when readLine is first executed. But it does not change any more after that. What is wrong with my code? I use `RandomAccessFile` instead of `FileInputStream` because seek() is faster than skip() when file is big.

```
String buffer;        
long offset;
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "r");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while (true) {
    offset = raf.getFilePointer(); // offset remains the same after 1st readLine. why?
    if ((buffer = br.readLine()) == null) // buffer has correct value.
        return;
………………………………
}
```

Comment: Think about what a buffered reader would do. It reads some of the file into a "buffer" to make access faster.

Comment: I'm amused that you're annoyed that `BufferedReader` buffers reads.

Answer (score 0):

Because `BufferedReader` is buffered. So it reads the data into it's buffer the first time and then just keeps it there until it needs more buffered data.

If you want to use a smaller buffer for testing purposes, try `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 1000);` or something. Your pointer should now increment by 1000 occasionally.

If you want your counter to work properly, you can do one of two things. Either you can count the characters you are receiving and then do some converting to byte lengths which you can use to make your own counter or you can use a `FileReader` with no buffering which will increment the counter the way you expect.

Update: It seems `FileReader` does something behind the scenes. I'd use something like `new CountingInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(raf.getFD()))` loop through the data in `byte` form, manually identify line endings while dumping the bytes into a `String`. Not the prettiest way, but the only way I can think of given `Reader`'s internal buffering. I think `CountingInputStream` is provided by Apache freely and it contains a `count` method or something like that.

Comment: I understand but I don't know how to change my code. Please link good exampe of BufferedReader.

Comment: Unexpectedly getFilePointer always returns the same value even if I change buffer size of BufferedReader to 10.

Comment: OK. the problem might just be with the reader itself. I tried it and just a FileReader doesn't work but an InputStream does. I think FileReader is doing some buffering behind the scenes. See my latest edit

Comment: I use getBytes to get offset. It works even though it is slow. Thank you anyway.